# cpan Cannot install mod_fcgid, don't know what it is

Tags: apache, perl, mod-fcgid

I have tried to install `mod_fcgid` on Centos 7 with no success. Actually I used `yum install` or `rpm` or `brewperl` but none worked

Then I tried `cpan` because it was my last shot. Maybe I am mistaken in syntax?

```
cpan mod_fcgid
Reading '/home/nick/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Mon, 27 Aug 2018 19:29:02 GMT
Warning: Cannot install mod_fcgid, don't know what it is.
Try the command

    i /mod_fcgid/

to find objects with matching identifiers.
```

I have googled but it seems like no one had an issue with this. And of course it exists for Centos; please [look here](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-x86_64/mod_fcgid-2.3.9-4.el7_4.1.x86_64.rpm.html)

Comment: `mod_fcgid` is an Apache module, not a Perl distribution or Perl module, so why would it be in Perlbrew or CPAN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you search on line for `install mod_fcgid Centos` then are multiple results. The second one is [*How to install mod_fcgid on RHEL or CentOS*](http://www.inetservicescloud.com/knowledgebase/how-to-install-mod_fcgid-on-rhel-or-centos/) and it consists of just three steps

> Here are the steps to install mod_fcgid on RHEL/CentOS:
>
> Step 1: To install mod_fcgid on CentOS / RHEL , first we will install EPEL repo .
>   #rpm -ivh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
>
> Step 2: Now install the mod_fcgid
>   #yum install mod_fcgid
>
> Step 3: to confirm package installed.
>   #rpm -qa|grep mod_fcgid